# Assign UV map to material (and consequently to object)

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm a Blender beginner (for some 20 years, I guess) - I've created a UV map by `Unwrap`ping a box-like object. When opened in Gimp, it was empty, so I took screenshot, put it over the empty image and put a little bit of graphics, saved, reloaded (`UV Editor` -> `Image` -> `Reload`) - probably not best workflow already.

So I've ended up on correct UV map image, but it's not related to the original object, since that has 3 materials, of which none is related to this UV map. I can't find this situation in any tutorial. I unassigned and deleted all 3 old materials (picture bellow taken before this), but still, the UV map does not show.

How do I assign this UV map to the object? Using a new material? Could you please advice a procedure?

---

EDIT: Here is an isolated object `blend` file and the associated texture: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13sNPYcLquSAiKPYN-4FJbySlc0UxD68i?usp=sharing][1].

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

EDIT 2: Some posts say, that starting from 2.8x one must assign image texture to material. I tested that first with a simple cube and it worked fine:

[image: Cube UV mapping]

But when I tested that with a real object, it doesn't apply the texture the way UV editor has it assigned:

[image: Real object UV mapping]

---

Comment: How did you get your UV map into Gimp? - You say it was empty, but if you'd used the UV > Export UV Layout menu in the UV editor you should be able to see the UV map in GIMP just as you can in Blender. You can then open a new layer in Gimp, set up your image using the UV layout as a reference, save just the image layer and use Image > Open to import it into Blender's UV editor.

Comment: @JohnEason I used `UV` -> `Image` -> `Save` to be able to open it with Gimp. Then from the UV Editor again `UV` -> `Image` -> `Reload` to get result there. Maybe that's the problem. I'll try `UV` -> `Export UV` and `Open` when I get to my computer. But I'm feeling this will not fix the fact, that the UV map is somehow not syncing with the object. I will try, though, thanks John!

Comment: @JohnEason As expected, the UV map is not applied to the object. It's somehow not attached. Apart from that, I am adopting the workflow you described, it's probably the way to do it.

Comment: When I select planes in the object one by one, parts (areas) of the UV map get highlighted. So I think the UV map *is* assigned. Maybe some display issue? Some posts say something about GLSL, but I don't know where to check/set it in my 2.82 version and they didn't describe a way to do it.

Comment: Your object is working as expected https://imgur.com/a/XTh99uw i'm not sure what's your process on applying the texture, try to see some tutorials on texture paint, also, as mentioned by John, the correct way to export the uv is with the UV menu > Export UV, but you have to have the whole faces selected

Comment: @Emir Yep, I tried like 3 tutorials, they seem to be same, but maybe I need specifically 2.82 tutorial(s). Will have a look again. I am using now Johns workflow and I do have all face selected. In the image I just demonstrated that selecting a plane on the objects selects the corresponding plane in the UV map - to prove it's indeed linked.